# If column value contains dictionary key populate other column value with dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, partial

If I have DataFrame:

```
df_d = {'Element':['customer full name','full name','name','religion','account number','lgbt','lgbt identity']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_d)
df['Match'} = ''
```

And I have dictionary:

```
d = {'name':'Contact', 'religio':'Behavioral', 'lgbt':'Identity'}
```

How can I populate df['Match'] with the dictionary value if the Element CONTAINS the dictionary key? I can have it populate the column for full matches:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
     if df['Element'][i] in d:
          df['Match'][i] = d[df['Element'][i]]
```

But I can't get it to work for partial Element matches. Sorry, my browser won't allow me to copy and paste the cell outputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) + [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

We can construct a *regex pattern* from the keys of the given mapping dictionary, then use this pattern to `extract` the capture group in regex pattern then `map` the capture group with the mapping dictionary

```
df['Match'] = df['Element'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(d.keys())})", expand=False).map(d)
```

---

```
              Element       Match
0  customer full name     Contact
1           full name     Contact
2                name     Contact
3            religion  Behavioral
4      account number         NaN
5                lgbt    Identity
6       lgbt identity    Identity
```